# How to run multiple threads on ASP.NET MVC efficiently?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've a scheduled task in my `ASP.NET MVC` site that nightly sends notifications for the users.

I've been sending and awaiting notifications one by one, but it's taking an hour to complete now, so I thought I should send them in batches.

```
int counter = 0;
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var user in users)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await user.SendNotificationAsync();
        counter++;
    }));

    if (tasks.Count >= 20)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        tasks.Clear();
    }
}

if(tasks.Any())
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    tasks.Clear();
}
```

But I've read that creating multiple threads is not efficient on the servers. How should I run multiple instances of the method on the server?

Comment: Or maybe because this is just a single scheduled task, has not a big effect on the server and is alright already?

Comment: "How should I run multiple instances of the method on the server?" How do you expect to do this without multiple threads?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto But multiple threads are evil. some way other than that maybe?

Comment: Evil to who? That's the most weird comment I've read on this site. Did you know that processors are advancing towards more cores instead of more power per core? That's a 90's way of thinking.

Comment: I think its fine. its not like running multiple thread for long time simultaneously. It only does its simple job and discarded.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: What does that post have to do at all with this?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That guy is causing all this problem: `If you have multiple calls to Task.Run, then the performance problems are compounded. On a busy server, this kind of implementation can kill scalability.
That’s why one of the principles of ASP.NET is to avoid using thread pool threads (except for the request thread that ASP.NET gives you, of course). More to the point, this means that ASP.NET applications should avoid Task.Run.`

Comment: First of all, that's for requests, not for scheduled tasks. Secondly, you don't even need to use `Task.Run` here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not following the best practices on TPL, here's a rewrite on how you should do it:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
int counter = 0; // not sure what this is for

foreach (var user in users)
{
    tasks.Add(user.SendNotificationAsync()); // do not create a wrapping task
    counter++; // not sure about this either

    // it won't ever be greater than 20
    if (tasks.Count == 20)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        tasks.Clear();
    }
}

if (tasks.Any())
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    tasks.Clear();
}
```

This is perfectly fine, also, because threads will be spawned and destroyed as soon as they are done.

Comment: Thanks. (that counter is to inform me later how much notifications are sent)

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks, I normally confuse them, not native language

Answer (score 1):

Just to shed light on what Camilo meant by his example was that, in your example, you were creating a new `Task` to monitor your awaitable task. So, essentially, you were not only creating twice the number of tasks needed, you were also chaining them up - a `Task` to monitor a `Task`, where the middle task is just a proxy which will be picked up from the Threadpool just to monitor another task from the Threadpool.

As the `user.SendNotificationAsync()` is an awaitable task anyway, you can directly add it to the `List<Task>` - tasks and `await` directly on it.

Hence his example.